# Rails 3 in controller test for field change

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the controller of a Rails 3 app, I'm trying to test if a field changes and then flash a message on the redirect page.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
class CostprojectsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @costproject = Costproject.find(params[:id])
    @costquestion = @costproject.costquestion
    nextpath = edit_costquestion_path(@costquestion) if params[:tab1]
    nextpath = costprojects_editcostestimates_path(:id => @costproject.id) if params[:tab2]
    nextpath = costprojects_editattachments_path(:id => @costproject.id) if params[:tab3]
    if nextpath == nil
      if User.current.admin?
        nextpath = costprojects_path
      else
        nextpath = clients_costcurrent_path
      end
    end
    flash[:success] = "Project Submitted" if @costproject.submit_date_changed?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @costproject.update_attributes(params[:costproject])
        format.html { redirect_to nextpath }
        format.json { render json: @costproject }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @costproject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the line not working:

```
flash[:success] = "Project Submitted" if @costproject.submit_date_changed?
```

@costproject.submit_date is a valid field - and it's getting updated during the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating your @costproject AFTER the if condition, I guess you should do it before.

You should consider doing it only if update_attributes returns true, as in following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @costproject.update_attributes(params[:costproject])
    flash[:success] = "Project Submitted" if @costproject.previous_changes.include?(:submit_date)
    format.html { redirect_to nextpath }
    format.json { render json: @costproject }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @costproject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried moving the code. But, for some reason the "if" isn't returning true. If I remove the "if" part, the flash shows up.

Comment: Check if @costproject.previous_changes contains something after the update_attributes, because it is likely that update_attributes clear any information returned by changed? methods

Comment: I added `flash[:success] = @costproject.changes` and got nothing

Comment: Try previous_changes, because my guess is changes get cleared as soon your obecjet is saved

Comment: You're right - it's in previous changed.  How do I code?  I tried `if @costproject.submit_date_previous_changed?`

Comment: See my updated answer, you just need to search for submit_date as a key in previous_changes